# "In order to" vs "To"

Tags: scientific-publishing

Can I always replace "In order to" with the shorter "To" in scientific writing?

**Example**

1. *In order to prevent corrupting the data, regular updates are required.*
2. *To prevent corrupting the data, regular updates are required.*

Answer (score 2):

I would think yes, since "in order" is a bit superfluous, but there are always exceptions in context. You can probably take it out most of the time (like 85 to 90 percent).

Comment: Formality seems to be the difference here.  "In order to" sounds more formal to me...maybe even ceremonial.  i.e. "...in order to form a more perfect union."  Agreed, generally it is excessive...